# Bug when formatting "%d - %d" in RTL on Samsung devices with Android 8.0

Tags: android, arabic, right-to-left

I have an app that supports RTL. When formatting a score between two teams I write something along the lines of:

```
t1.setText(String.format(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-MA"), "%d - %d", 1, 0));
```

Which outputs "0 - 1" on the Android emulator if my textfield is set to textDirection="locale", on all my test-devices running Android 8 and Android 9, on my Huawei and basically everywhere. But if I test this on a Samsung S7 with Android 8.0 it returns "1 - 0". I tested both on a physical device and on the device lab from Samsung: https://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action

Is this the wrong way of doing this? How can I format the score so it works on both LTR and RTL on all devices when I have a single text field containing the score? This works perfectly on most devices out there but I seem to be missing something in regards to why it breaks on Samsung devices.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Home team won 1-0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layoutDirection="locale"
        android:text="1-0"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1-0"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t3"
        android:textDirection="locale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1-0"
        />
    <TextView
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:id="@+id/t4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1-0"
        />
    <TextView
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:id="@+id/t5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1-0"
        />
    <TextView
        android:textDirection="locale"
        android:id="@+id/t6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1-0"
        />
    <TextView
        android:textDirection="locale"
        android:id="@+id/t7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1-0"
        />
    <TextView
        android:textDirection="locale"
        android:id="@+id/t8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1-0"
        />
    <TextView
        android:textDirection="locale"
        android:id="@+id/t9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1-0"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

App code:

```
t1.setText(String.format(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-MA"), "%d - %d", 1, 0));
t2.setText(String.format(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-MA"), "%d - %d", 1, 0));
t3.setText(String.format(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-MA"), "%d - %d", 1, 0));
t4.setText(String.format(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-MA"), "%d - %d", 1, 0));
t5.setText(String.format(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-MA"), "%d - %d", 1, 0));
t6.setText(BidiFormatter.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-MA")).unicodeWrap(String.format(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-MA"), "%d - %d", 1, 0), TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.ANYRTL_LTR));
t7.setText(BidiFormatter.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-MA")).unicodeWrap(String.format(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-MA"), "%d - %d", 1, 0), TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.RTL));
t8.setText("\u200F" + String.format(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-MA"), "%d - %d", 1, 0));
t9.setText("ع" + String.format(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-MA"), "%d - %d", 1, 0));
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Emulator screenshot: 
[image]

Samsung S7 screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: What locale is on your phone? Did you use the Force RTL layout developer option? What happens if you call `Locale.setDefault(getResources().getConfiguration().locale)` before `setContentView()`? What's inside `getResources().getConfiguration()`? (Run the debugger and copy the output in your question. I'm interested in `locale` and `layoutDirection`.)

Comment: I've tested with phone set to ar-MA. If I set it to ar-EG with Eastern Arabic digits then everything works great. Let me get back to the other questions in a few minutes.

Comment: I got the exact same result even with the Locale.setDefault(). And the S7 and local emulator had the same result from the log statements: 

Log.w("RTL", getResources().getConfiguration().locale.toString());
Log.w("RTL", getResources().getConfiguration().locale.toLanguageTag());
Log.w("RTL", getResources().getConfiguration().getLayoutDirection() + "");

WARNING 02-05 22:44:05.423 28972 28972  RTL ar_MA
WARNING 02-05 22:44:05.423 28972 28972  RTL ar-MA
WARNING 02-05 22:44:05.423 28972 28972  RTL 1

Comment: I don't suppose they write left-to-right Arabic in Morocco... I can only think of pinpointing it down to a version of Android. You can setup the S7 in Genymotion emulator on various versions of Android. How do other apps behave? Any other app broken or working?

Comment: @EugenPechanec I tested AWS Device Farm and this seems to apply to all Samsung devices, while all the other vendors (LG, Google, Motorola, Asus) show it correctly. So maybe Samsung has their own text widget that breaks it. Since it is only happening if you have two %d inside a String.format I guess the bug is pretty unique to us and we just have to add some ugly workarounds :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this bug/feature on Samsung devices can in my case have a workaround:

```
String RTL_INDICATOR = "\u200f";
t1.setText(String.format(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-MA"), "%d %s- %d", 1, RTL_INDICATOR, 0));
```

This Right-to-left-mark (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f/index.htm) has to be inserted in the middle of the two integers. If inserted at the beginning of the string it doesn't resolve the issue.

The code gets pretty ugly as I have to do this in a number of places but it works on all devices across all Android versions (that I've tested) so marking this as the answer for now.

Answer (score -1):

add

```
     android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

to your

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
```

Comment: It didn't work, compare the code and the second image.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't do anything as the app supports RTL and locale is a RTL locale. As I mentioned it all works great on 10+ devices I have for test but once did a test on Samsung S7 with Android 8.0 it failed.

Comment: because the most of my Apps in Arabic ,so I use it often when I face the same problem